# IdentityDbContext - IdentityRole is not part of the context

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I'm creating a new MVC application which uses Windows Authentication using Microsoft OWIN.

I want to create repositories for all the classes belonging to the database for authentication, therefore I've customized the IdentityDbContext class as follows:

```
public class nDataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<string, ApplicationUserRole>
{ }

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{ }

public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string>
{ }

public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string>
{ }

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{ }
```

However, when I want to upgrade the database using the package manager command, I'll receive the following error:

The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution. In the IdentityManager, I was still using the interface instead of the Implementation (ApplicationRole).

That solved the issue.